# How to set a Boolean from one class to a JTextField in another class in java

Tags: java, string

I have a method in the `Family class`

I want to add the value of the method to the `JTextField` from the `Driver Class.`

Eclipse keeps showing errors offering to make the method a string. Any help on how to do this would be great.

method

```
public boolean AnswerCall(String r) {
    boolean AnswerCall = true; 

    if(r == "Brother") { 
        AnswerCall = true; 
    }else {
        AnswerCall = false; 
    } 
    return AnswerCall;
}
```

How I am currently calling it from the driver class that is `extending Family.`

```
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(AnswerCall());
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, I can't see how this has anything to do with inheritance. You should also follow Java naming conventions, and it would be clearer to just write: `return r.equals("Brother");`

Comment: JTextField doesn't have any constructor with argument `boolean` and that's why Eclipse is offering to change the return type of `AnswerCall` method to `String`. You could alway do `JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(Boolean.toString(AnswerCall()));`

Comment: I appreciate all your comments but none of that makes any sense to me. Would one of you mine elaborating or answering the question using my code so I can understand better.

Comment: There is no 'boolean object' here either, any more than there is any inheritance. The method you posted should be entirely replaced by a single String.equals() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public boolean AnswerCall(String r) {
    return r.equals("Brother");
}
```

and for textfield

```
String txt = Boolean.toString(AnswerCall("Sister"));//converting boolean to string value
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(txt);
```

Comment: Ok this fixed the error. But this code just changes the value to Brother. I need it to be true if brother and false if not brother. Based on another method holding the value brother called relationship

Comment: @NichoDiaz no, it doesn't change it to brother. this code does exactly what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: Thank you what you have given me is working! But Yes I need to to say true or false. True if brother is in the string and false if not. what am I missing?

Comment: can u tell me how r u passing the vaules to this method? u can use this line "return r.eqaulsIgnoreCase("Brother");" to make case in-sensitive

Comment: Your great. thanks man I got it now. I appreciate you. I appreciate everyones help.

Comment: we are happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `JTextField` has not a constructor taking a `boolean` parameter. so when you do:

```
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(AnswerCall());
```

The compilation will fail because `AnswerCall()` is retuning a `boolean`, while it should be return a String, so change the `AnswerCall()` to be return a String like:

**Note**: don't compare a Strings using `==`, use `.equals()` instead

```
public String AnswerCall(String r) {
String answerCall = ""; 

    if(r.equals("Brother")) { 
        answerCall = "True"; 
    } 
    else {
        answerCall = "false"; 
    } 
  return answerCall;
```

}

Comment: I still get error on the return line. in this method you added

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `equals` to compare string in java like:

```
public boolean AnswerCall(String r) {
    return r.equals("Brother");
}
```

and you can don't use a new Boolean var.

**Edit:**

for the constructoryou can add an empty string like this:

```
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(Family().AnswerCall()+"");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have the error when calling on the method to the JTextField.

Comment: So you should use the class name like `Drivee.AnswerCall()+""` try this

Comment: I am calling on it from driver. the AnswerCall is in family

Comment: which class contains the method AnswerCall?

Comment: Family contains AnswerCall. Driver has the GUI I am extending Family 
public Driver extends Family

Comment: Try to call it by the name of class `Family`. don't forget the import
Try : JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(`Family().AnswerCall()+"");

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not able to catchup with all the comments, I am going to elaborate two ways to do it:

**First Way**

Change your method as suggested by @Dinosaur

```
public boolean AnswerCall(String r) {
    return r.equals("Brother");
}
```

and then make the JTextField object as following:

```
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(Boolean.toString(AnswerCall("your string here")));
```

**Second Way**

use the method suggested by @Salah

```
public String AnswerCall(String r) {
    String answerCall = ""; 
    if(r.equals("Brother"))
        answerCall = "True"; 
    else {
        answerCall = "false"; 
    return answerCall;
}
```

and then create the JTextField object as following:

```
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(AnswerCall("your string here"));
```

Comment: Bother ways give me the same error. it offers to turn to string,
JTextField jt9 = new JTextField(AnswerCall(ADD STUFF HERE ));

Comment: In both the cases covered here, only `String` is being passed to `JTextField`'s constructor